# Why does Polymer add class to child elements automatically?

Tags: polymer

When embed <template> in <dom-module>, I find each child element in <template> has been added a className, the same as the component name. Why does Polymer design like this? Is there any consideration? How can I avoid this?

e.g.:

```
<dom-module id="my-greeting">
  <template>
    <style include="shared-styles"></style>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
    <h2 class="page-title">{{greeting}}</h2>
    <span class="paper-font-body2">Update text to change the greeting.</span>
    <!-- Listens for "input" event and sets greeting to <input>.value -->
    <input class="paper-font-body2" value="{{greeting::input}}">
  </template>

  <script>
    (function() {
      'use strict';

      Polymer({
        is: 'my-greeting',

        properties: {
          greeting: {
            type: String,
            value: 'Welcome!',
            notify: true
          }
        }
      });
    })();
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

The dom structure in browser is:

```
<my-greeting class="x-scope my-greeting-0">
  <h2 class="page-title style-scope my-greeting">Welcome!</h2>
  <span class="paper-font-body2 style-scope my-greeting">Update text to change the greeting.</span>
  <!-- Listens for "input" event and sets greeting to <input>.value -->
  <input class="paper-font-body2 style-scope my-greeting">
</my-greeting>
```

Every child element in my-greeting has a className 'my-greeting'.

Comment: That's how it works, which I believe has to do with Shady DOM's CSS handling. It also does all sorts of other automagic. Why exactly is this a problem for you?

Answer (score 4):

It's how they polyfill lack of css isolation when shadow DOM is not supported.

In Chrome, you have to manually enable native shadow DOM usage for polymer and you won't see that behavior. Add

```
window['Polymer'] = window['Polymer'] || {};
window['Polymer']['dom'] = 'shadow';
```

Before you include the polymer component on your page and you'll get native shadow dom support.

Answer (score 0):

Chad's answer is right.

I look into the source code of Polymer, and find the source code doing this: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/master/src/lib/style-transformer.html#L110. There is a comment on this function: Given a string of cssText and a scoping string (scope), returns a string of scoped css where each selector is transformed to include a class created from the scope. ShadowDOM selectors are also transformed (e.g. :host) to use the scoping selector.